# Query problem in Firestore with OR filter and FieldPath.documentId combination

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

With only one document (myUid) in the userCollection, I executed the following function to retrieve documents other than myUid.

```
static Future<String?> getUnmatchedUser(String? myUid) async{   
  print('getUnmatchedUser: myUid == $myUid');

    try {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _userCollection
                                        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isNotEqualTo: myUid)
                                        .where(Filter.or(
                                          Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: 'en'),
                                          Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: 'ja')))
                                        .get();

        print('querySnapshot.docs.length == ${querySnapshot.docs.length}');
            return null;
              
        } catch (e) {
            print('getUnmatchedUser: ERROR == $e');
            return null;
        }
}
```

In the above function, the number of documents retrieved is expected to be 0. However, even though a document matches myUid is excluded, it’s retrieved and the number of retrieved documents is 1.

Below is the screenshots of firestore's console and VScode's console at that time.
[image]
[image]

On the other hand, if the function is executed excluding the line using the where with OR filter as shown below, the document is not retrieved. This is expected behavior.

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _userCollection
                                    .where(FieldPath.documentId, isNotEqualTo: myUid)
                                    .get();
```

What is the reason why a document matching myUid is retrieved in the former function? Please tell me what the problem is, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as in your previous question, you're using the wrong operator here. If you want to test whether a single-value field has one of a number of values, us the [`whereIn` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

```
.where("queried_language", whereIn: ['en', 'ja']),
```

At this stage I recommend that you take time to read the Firebase documentation on [Firestore queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) from start to finish before continuing. Spending time on that now, will save many times more time (and questions) going forward.

Comment: Thank for you advice, Mr Frank. I have a question. I have read the official guide and the following . I would like to know exactly what the conditions for use of the Filter.or operator are. am I understanding that the condition for use of the Filter.or operator is "to compare one or more fields with two or more values and select a document that matches at least one of those values"? If correct, it seems to me that the code in this case matches the conditions for use of the Filter.or operator. I am wondering why it is not functioning properly nonetheless.

Comment: [Querying flexibly in Firestore with OR operator](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/use-more-boolean-operators-in-firestory-queries?hl=en)

Comment: The example in your question is a type of query that you'd use a `whereIn` clause for, as I showed in my answer. --- An `OR` clause is typically when you want to have conditions across multiple fields. Say you have a chat app where content is approved (by some server-side process, or human) before it's shown to everyone. You could do an OR query getting messages that are either from the user themselves OR that are approved, so that a user always sees all their own messages and approved messages from everyone.